# dragging a copy of an image doesn't drop another one on top

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I used the standard javascript code for drag and drop and modified it to drag a copy of the image at a drop area. What i cant figure out, because i no nothing about javascript, is what to do in order to replace/swap the dropped image when i drag another one on top of it. Please help!!I would really appreciate it! I used the following code and i would prefer if there is a workaround on the current code, if not is there any simple way to solve this? Many thanks!

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function dragEnter(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
}

function drop(ev) {
var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));

ev.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/34d5g/)
 when you drag image on drop area (blue div on dx) if in drop area there is an image this image disappears an new dragged image show
 
The jQuery code you need is

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.dr').on("dragstart", function (event) {
              var dt = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
              dt.setData('Text', $(this).attr('id'));
            });

        $('#dropArea').on("dragenter dragover drop", function (event) { 
           event.preventDefault();
           if (event.type === 'drop') {
               $(this).find('.dr').remove()
              var data = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text',$(this).attr('id'));
              de=$('#'+data).clone();
              de.css({'position':'absolute','top':0+'px','left':0+'px'}).appendTo($(this)); 
           };
       });
   });  
</script>
```

For this result i use drag drop api html5

Comment: @user3582156 if you really like it you can flag in green my answer, thanks;)